# How can I make masonary grid with Vimeo videos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, responsive

I want to make a responsive masonry grid with vimeo videos that are embeded via iframes.
But it seems a bit hard because all the videos have different sizes and the videos will be changed dynamically.
I want them to look like on Pexels.com
How can I do that?

I tried grid and flexbox layouts but the div keeps its height or width, the video shrinks itself because it gets its values from inside the iframe. I have to give the iframes the width and height of the videos they got inside.

The videos has different sizes like 1920x1080 or 1080x1920 so they have to fit perfectly with aspect ratio, how can I achieve that?

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.videos {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
flex-wrap:wrap;
    .video {
        width: max-content;
    }
}
```

PUG

```
.videos.grid
    .video.grid-item
        iframe(src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/438140062?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0", frameborder="0", width="100%",height="100%",allow="autoplay;fullscreen",allowfullscreen)
    .video.grid-item
        iframe(src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/419704737?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0", frameborder="0", width="100%",height="100%",allow="autoplay;fullscreen",allowfullscreen)
    .video.grid-item
        iframe(src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/438140062?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0", frameborder="0", width="100%",height="100%",allow="autoplay;fullscreen",allowfullscreen)
    .video.grid-item
        iframe(src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/419704737?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0", frameborder="0", width="100%",height="100%",allow="autoplay;fullscreen",allowfullscreen)
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: I did write some code, as I said I tried flexbox and css grid but they didn't work so I didn't write my code here

Comment: You need to put your code here. SO is not a code writing service. SO purpose is for debugging, with assistance from you. I didnt downvote you but you will likely get more downvotes if you dont post code or simply close it. Btw css `width` or `height` respects aspect ratio, but not both together.

Comment: @GetSet I understand you thank you but the code I wrote will not be enough... :/ But I will edit and add my code thanks.

Comment: Its understood that the code you post will not be enough. If it were 100% working then you wouldnt be here. Upvoted you. Maybe that might give it more attention.

Comment: @GetSet: U r a wonderful person. Straight to the point. My upvote for this new guy as well :) Like they say "Life outside is a dangerous place" May be new guys here would feel the same if they keep getting down votes :)

Comment: @M.Uslu: Upvoted for you. I am really busy right now. Would not take this challenge right now. Would Advice you to first simply create a masonry Layout first using CSS-Grids. Later you will put videos. Wish you all the Best :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thank you I did make masonry actually but iframes make problem, I will change codes couple hours later with new ones,

Comment: Instead of iframes @M.Uslu, maybe have a jpeg or other photo link as a stand in?

Comment: @GetSet Exactly Mate !!! I was also thinking the same. What our struggles have been right from the Engineering... We still face challenges :)

Comment: @M. Uslu... Could you Share your Masonry Code... I would like to help you with rest of the journey :) Put your HTML and CSS on Codepen and share the link :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather https://codepen.io/mertcanuslu/pen/oNzErVg thank you so much, I have been testing some js libraries but as I said, iframes doesnt fill all the space and they left blank areas so they dont look like masonary, also videos are getting really smaller, I want them to fill all the space in aspect ratio, like 3 items per row etc.

Comment: I am trying to Change the Styling of Each IFrame from Javascript :) I was really close to change the inline-style that is being set to each Iframe. Only if we can change these inline styles we will be able to arrange our videos correctly. I was extremely close but got the Cross-origin IFrame access Error which happens with Iframe. Try taking it from here on  your local machine :)

Comment: Here is my codepen link : https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/LYRQKwE?editors=0002.... try to simply add new CSS within my <style></style> tags and use !important with each... keep checking developer window to debug stuff

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thank you so much but I actually didn't understand something, can't we make the divs bigger like in this screenshot? https://prnt.sc/web2js

Comment: The Real ISSUE is accessing Iframe from our Page...And we cannot directly change styles of iframes we have to use Javascript. and use contentWindow or contentDocument which ever is supported. That's what I have done... Now you can try setting new styles as well. I have made a template for that ...---------------------------------------- // doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + `<style>
    //       #player{
    //      width: calc(100vh) !important;
    //       height: calc(100vw) !important;
    //       }
    // </style>`;   This thing

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thanks but I figured out that I may use some library to show videos instead of Iframes, and here is the result in another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65555711/how-to-make-masonry-with-plyr-js-and-minimasonry-js could you help me there please?